# Java- Involving objects and multiple classes

Tags: java, class, object, methods

My problem is that for the getTime(); command, you need all of the speed, handling, xcord, ycord, and the terrainDifficultry variables to have an answer, yet I can only call getTime(); from the mb1 class. Basically, I keep getting 0.0 when i get to System.out getTime() and I don't know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main_MoonRace {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the speed of the moonbuggy as an integer.");
        int s = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the handling of the moonbuggy (between 0-0.9)");
        double h = keyboard.nextDouble();
        moonbuggy mb1 = new moonbuggy(s,h);

        System.out.println("Enter the x-coordinate of where the moonbuggy will be headed to as an integer.");
        int xcord = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the y-coordinate of where the moonbuggy will be headed to as an integer.");
        int ycord = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the difficulty of the terrain that the moonbuggy will be experiencing (integer from 1-10).");
        int terrainDifficulty = keyboard.nextInt();
        MoonLocation mL1 = new MoonLocation(xcord,ycord,terrainDifficulty);

        System.out.println(mb1.getTime());
    }
}
```

**moonbuggy.java**

```
public class moonbuggy {    
    private int speed = 1;
    private double handling = 0;
    moonbuggy(){
        return;
    }
    moonbuggy(int s, double h){
        speed = s;
        handling = h;

        return;
    }
    public void setSpeed (int s){
        speed = s;
    }
    public void setHandling (double h){
        handling = h;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    public double getHandling(){
        return handling;
    }
    MoonLocation obj1 = new MoonLocation();

    public double getTime(){
        double time = (((obj1.getdistance())/(getSpeed()))*(obj1.getTerrain())*(1-(getHandling())));
        return time;
    }
}
```

**MoonLocation.java**

```
public class MoonLocation {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int terrain = 1;

    MoonLocation(){
        return;
    }
    MoonLocation(int xcord, int ycord, int terrainDifficulty){
        x= xcord;
        y = ycord;
        terrain = terrainDifficulty;

        return;
    }

    public void setX (int xcord){
        x = xcord;
    }
    public void setY (int ycord){
        y = ycord;
    }
    public void setTerrain (int terrainDifficulty){
        terrain = terrainDifficulty;
    }
    public int getX () {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY () {
        return y;
    }
    public int getTerrain () {
        return terrain;
    }
    public double getdistance () {
        double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x,2))+(Math.pow(y,2)));
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you're constructing a `MoonLocation` and then completely ignoring it is indicative of a problem... but you haven't really asked a question, which makes it difficult to help you...

Comment: You need to give the code for moonbuggy

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this part of code in your `moonbuggy` class (note that by convention a class should always start with uppercase in java).

```
MoonLocation obj1 = new MoonLocation();
public double getTime(){
    double time = (((obj1.getdistance())/(getSpeed()))*(obj1.getTerrain())*(1-(getHandling())));
    return time;
}
```

You instanciate a `MoonLocation` without any parameters, then you access it in your `getTime` method. This explain why you always get 0.0 as result when calling `getTime`.

Now modify your `getTime` method to

```
public double getTime(MoonLocation location){
    return (((location.getdistance())/(getSpeed()))*(location.getTerrain())*(1-(getHandling())));
}
```

**Notice that I removed the time variable as it is completly useless there.**

And change in your main

```
MoonLocation mL1 = new MoonLocation(xcord,ycord,terrainDifficulty);
System.out.println(mb1.getTime());
```

To

```
MoonLocation mL1 = new MoonLocation(xcord,ycord,terrainDifficulty);
System.out.println(mb1.getTime(mL1));
```

Also, please remove the unused `MoonLocation obj1 = new MoonLocation()` in your `moonbuggy` class.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem lies with your code. In the first place, you are creating an object of MoonLocation in Main_MoonRace class under main() method as :

```
MoonLocation mL1 = new MoonLocation(xcord,ycord,terrainDifficulty);
```

Here, an object of MoonLocation is created and initialized with xcord, ycord, and terrainDifficulty values.

Now, in your MoonBuggy class, again you are creating an object of MoonLocation as :

```
MoonLocation obj1 = new MoonLocation();
```

Here, only an empty object of MoonLocation class is created.

Now, when you call :

```
obj1.getDistance();   It will return 0 only.
```

Below is the corrected code for MoonBuggy class.

```
public class Moonbuggy {    
    private int speed = 1;
    private double handling = 0;

    Moonbuggy(){}

    Moonbuggy(int s, double h){
        speed = s;
        handling = h;
    }
    public void setSpeed (int s){
        speed = s;
    }
    public void setHandling (double h){
        handling = h;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    public double getHandling(){
        return handling;
    }

    private MoonLocation obj1;

    public MoonLocation getObj1() {
        return obj1;
    }

    public void setObj1(MoonLocation obj1) {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
    }

    public double getTime(){
        double time = (((obj1.getdistance())/(getSpeed()))*(obj1.getTerrain())*(1-(getHandling())));
        return time;
    }
}
```

and an addtion in the main() method :

```
MoonLocation mL1 = new MoonLocation(xcord,ycord,terrainDifficulty);
        mb1.setObj1(mL1);  // set the MoonLocation object
        System.out.println(mb1.getTime());
```

Now , you will get the proper output